# Mongoose Querying on Array of Object or Virtual for array of Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following Mongoose schema as defined on [this page](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals)

```
const AuthorSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});



const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
  comments: [{
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
    content: String
  }]
});
```

Now I want to create a virtual on AuthorSchema to get the BlogPosts which have comments of that author.

I tried creating a virtual function but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `virtual` and `methods` can solve your problems:

Virtual:

```
// Model
AuthorSchema.virtual('blogPosts').get(function () {
  return this.model('BlogPost').find({
    comments: { $elemMatch: { author: this._id } },
  })
});

// Usage
const author = await Author.findById(id);
const blogPosts = await author.blogPosts;
```

Methods:

```
// Model
AuthorSchema.method.blogPosts= function (cb) {
  return this.model('BlogPost').find({
    comments: { $elemMatch: { author: this._id } },
  }, cb)
};

// Usage
const author = await Author.findById(id);
const blogPosts = await author.blogPosts();
```